# Connections issue while interactiing with SQL from Azure Function

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-functions

We are talking to Azure SQL Db using Azure Function. We use latest version of Azure functions which is 3.1 along with .net core 3 and EF core.

Recently we saw below error message in our logging
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Resource ID : 1. The request limit for the elastic pool is 420 and has been reached. See 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=267637' for assistance.
Also looking at the app insights, we found that connections reached around 1400 during that time.

[image]

We add DbContext to the services using following statement in the startup file.

```
    builder.Services.AddDbContextPool<OurDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer("connectionstring");
    });
```

OurDbContext class has following constructor,

```
public OurDbContext(DbContextOptions<OurDbContext> options)
    : base(options)
{
}
```

And then we inject OurDbContext class in different repositories which uses this context to talk to SQL.
Similar to below:

```
public class Repo : IRepo
{
  public Repo(OurDbContext ourDbContext)
  {

  }
  
  public async Task AddAsync(Entity entity)
  {
    ourDbContext.AddAsync(entity);
    ourDbContext.SaveChangesAsync()
  }
}
```

We inject these repos in Function classes and call above methods such as

```
await _repo.AddAsync()
```

Do you see any issues in above structure since the number of connections that got opened were a lot?

I believe for some reason the context/connection are not getting disposed once the function completes the execution.

Was thinking to use using statement for dbContext so that it gets disposed as soon as we are done with the db query execution. But, then I am not sure if we can use AddDbContextPool in the startup class as it need options. Also, OurDbContext is binded to this options. Might have to use onConfiguring method in OurDbContext class which I don't know how to use along with AddDbContextPool?

Any suggestions would be very useful. Thank you!

**Update 1**
Updated for more detail related to question in the comment:
Here is what my method has:

```
public async Task<List<EntityXyz>()
{
    var xyzToBeUpdated = new EntityXyz()
    {
        mapping of few fields;
    }
    
    OurDbContext.Update(xyzToBeUpdated);
    
    var xyzToBeAdded = new EntityXyz
    {
        mapping of few fields;
    }
    
    await OurDbContext.AddRangeAsync(xyzToBeAdded);

    await OurDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    xyzToBeAdded.Add(xyzToBeUpdated);
    return xyzToBeAdded;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you really do have that many concurrent users or devices calling your functions, in which case you either need to scale out, or scale up your resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DbContext instances and or Disposing of them is ***NOT*** your problem here.

> The request limit for the elastic pool is 420 and has been reached

A *request* in SQL Azure terms is a single executing *Query*, do not mistake this with *Sessions* that roughly correlate to your DbContext connection.

- I say roughly because connection pooling occurs under the hood.

This article spells it all out in plain terms: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support/tasks-workers-threads-scheduler-sessions-connections-requests/ba-p/333990

> The error is simply stating that you have too many *concurrent* queries operating against the database for your current subscription level.

This is an easy scenario to run into with *Azure Functions*, *Logic apps* and other *micro-service* architectures, especially if you have workflows that involve long chains of services that may be calling each other or sequences where one input message generates many output messages.

You should to analyze the message flow through your solution, for instance, how many instances of each function are running at the time when you hit the resource limit - who is the culprit? What triggers this function to be called so frequently?

I use the following simple query to get a snapshot of the actual requests that are running now, The actual SQL statement can be useful in tracking down associated code, but seeing too many or unexpected hosts can indicate that scale out scenarios have gone rampant:

```sql
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(ST.text, (QS.statement_start_offset/2) + 1,
    ((CASE statement_end_offset
        WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(st.text)
        ELSE QS.statement_end_offset END
            - QS.statement_start_offset)/2) + 1) AS statement_text
       , sess.login_name, sess.login_time, sess.host_name
       , conn.client_net_address
       , QS.session_id, QS.connection_id, QS.command, QS.blocking_session_id, QS.deadlock_priority, QS.estimated_completion_time
     FROM sys.dm_exec_requests AS QS
     -- Join on connections for specifics about how the connection was established
     INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections conn ON conn.connection_id = QS.connection_id
     -- Join on sessions to get the login name
     INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions sess ON sess.session_id =QS.session_id
     -- parse the SQL text for the running query
     CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(QS.sql_handle) as ST
ORDER BY start_time DESC;
```

You *should* always see this running query in the list. If you are currently hitting the max, run this a few times until you squeeze in (your apps should start to drop out due to the exceptions)

---

### Common Runtime / Design Scenarios that can lead to high concurrent query rates:

Without having the results from your analysis, the cause of issues like this can be broadly categorized into the following:

**Lazy Loading Database Context**
Sometimes this is simply caused through DbContext or Data Repos that have lazy loading enabled. Lazy-Loading can greatly simplify coding, especially in login chains of logic because you don't need to know in advance what records and fields to retrieve into memory. However in a system that has many users or many instances of the app calling the same database, as is usually the case with *Azure Functions*, then simple logic loops might be causing data to be re-queried at a much higher rate than you are expecting, especially if you are using asynchronous or parallel processing.

- For service/function architecture, think of *Lazy Loading* as *Lazy Programming*... eagerly loading will reduce the calls to the database to precisely the code where you expect it to occur.

**Long chain of interconnected asynchronous events**
If your *Functions* call other services or may trigger other functions that in turn may trigger others... Try to reduce the scenarios where the database needs to be called. If in the pipeline you see many of the same requests, or you know that each function call has an init process that loads records or messages from the database before processing, consider changing the logic so that the first call retrieves the data and passes some or all of this data to the next step.

- Remember that *async* processing has the potential to run multiple processes *concurrently*, perhaps you can reduce the concurrency by moving some of the logic to more synchronous processing.
- See the next point about [Event Hubs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/event-hubs/) and [Queues](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/services/storage/queues/)...

**Attempting Real Time Message/Telemetry Processing:**
This is common in IoT projects, but can come up in a lot of places, we often feel compelled to complete an operation immediately when it is requested. If you are indeed receiving hundreds of legitimate concurrent requests to your functions then you should consider using [Event Hubs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/event-hubs/) or [Queues](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/services/storage/queues/) to decouple the execution of your functions from their requests.

- A simple way to do this is to change the current function so that it puts the incoming request on a queue (or into the Hub if you need to support higher frequencies or many levels of concurrency). Then you move the previous logic into a new function that operates on a *Queue* or *EventHub trigger*, these trigger mechanisms allow you to configure the maximum number of concurrent processes and the batch size of messages to process effectively throttling your process pipeline to give you some control over how many queries hit your database at any given time.

**Custom or Real-Time Logging Scenarios:**
If you have implemented custom logging routines that log requests, status or exceptions to the same database (or a database in the same elastic pool) then these operations can easily blow out your request limits, consider logging to a different database or using a logging framework that caches logs and periodically flushes them to the database, [NLog](https://nlog-project.org/) is as good as any, but you should also consider Azure App Insights as you are already integrating to Azure resources.

- Under normal load, you may not notice any issues, however if you aggressively log exceptions, once you start to hit the *DTU* or *request* limits every new request at that time will log the exception, and worse the logging of the exception may itself also fail and trigger another log... (I've seen it happen) This can quickly cause exponential superfluous requests to the Db that further strangle your application

**Aggressive monitoring / polling:**
The last scenario that comes to mind is if your extended application has dashboards or reports or a UI or custom queue or timer patterns that mean something is frequently (perhaps on a timer) running queries against the database. *It may not be your Functions at all...* Where possible this sort of logic should be constrained so that there is a single instance of your code that does the polling and orchestrates other operations.

- Polling code is usually easy to convert to [Azure Queue](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/services/storage/queues/) based processing, polling the Queue is far more efficient than polling the database, and it doesn't count to your request count.
- If the bulk of the high concurrency requests are read-only, then you could also exploit readonly-replacas of the databases in Azure, offloading the read requests to a different data connection altogther.

Comment: Thank you. That's a great explanation. Looks like our organization uses SQL Elastic pool. This project being recently started uses Azure SQL. I am currently researching about SQL Elastic pool. And, it seems it was caused due to different apps calling,using same elastic pool. Since, we use app insights for logging from azure function, any idea or is there any specific metric thru which we can find how many SQL connections gets opened from our Functions and closed on a given day/minute in App insights? The above metric snapshot provides all kind of connections like httpClient, SQL, redis etc.

Comment: I've only used elastic pool in one project, that brings different challenges, but the advice works just the same. If you have multiple projects or types of users accessing the same database I would assign different SQL user accounts to each workload type, that will help isolate which _user_ is causing the workload in app insights.

Comment: Don't focus on the _connections_ though, your issue is _concurrent queries_ which is very transient. Insights can certainly help, but you need to understand the mechanics of your solution first, what have you implemented to throttle the requests to the database? It sounds like your design is simply allowing everything either synchronously or parallel in real time. Consider the SQL Intelligence feed as well - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/intelligent-insights-overview

Comment: yes, it seems it was nothing related to code issue but too much requests to the same elastic pool. Hence I have marked the answer correct.

Comment: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
Object name: 'OurDbContext'.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.CheckDisposed()

Comment: at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Update[TEntity](TEntity entity)                              Due to lack of space, I have the wrote the method used in above question as update 1, any idea or suggestions would be of great help? Searching online shows that this is basically caused when you are not waiting for the task to complete. In this case we do not see we are skipping that anywhere.

Comment: I can only speculate on the limited code you have provided, but if _DI_ is injecting your `OurDbContext` then your _DI_ management needs to be responsible for disposing it. So for instance because the context object is passed into `Repo`, that class does not actually control it and cannot _know_ if it is being used or referenced by other class, so you would expect the possibility of `ObjectDisposedException` being raised somewhere.

Comment: There's two main patterns with managing the context, implement `using` blocks, where you create a new instance of the _context_ as a local variable, attach/load your entities and perform operations on them, save and close the _context_. Otherwise the _context_ is stored as an instance member and methods on the class all operate against that context. If the _context_ is member level, then your class should only be responsible with disposing that instance IF it was also responsible for creating it.

Comment: To reduce the uncertainty, you can change your operational methods like `Task<List<EntityXyz>()` to accept the context as a parameter, in this way your method doesn't care about management of the context at all, it is up to the caller. In micro-services style architecture I find lots of benefits to this, but if you go that way, consider marking the task as static. Exploring this further is now off-topic for this post, however I'm happy to continue in chat or you could post a follow up question for techniques on managing either context lifetime or how to throttle calls through queues and hubs